# WordPress WorkFlow Modfications

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, workflow

I would like to ask a help about Zensor which is a plugin
that you publish a post then a moderator approves the post to be published on the WordPress blog site.

When a post is awating for approval, each awaiting post is appearing "waiting moderation". But, I dont want any link appears before moderator approval.

Actually I found the joining sentence below;

1- Must be added to the end of JOIN part of any query:

```
LEFT JOIN wp_zensor ON ID = wp_zensor.post_id
```

2- Must be added to the end of WHERE condition :

```
AND wp_zensor.moderation_status = 'approved'
```

Could you please show me; where should I add these modification on the category link presentation below:

```
<h2>Politics</h2>
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=31&showposts=1"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></b>
<?php the_content_limit(140, "devamı &raquo;"); ?>
<div class="hppostmeta">
<p><?php the_time('j F Y, H:i'); ?> | <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Or any general solutions will be welcomed.

Comment: I believe Zensor is a very old plugin and newer versions of WordPress already have moderation functionality built in. What version of WordPress are you running? There may be a much easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @The very lastest version of WP, If there is the way, could you please tell me how? Since my wordpress blog has many users, and 5 editörs.
Th recent system is:
The members publishes their posts, and then the editörs recive an email that there is a post awaiting to be published, and then if they apprives the post then it is published on the blog.
regards and cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more current versions of WordPress, "Contributors" can submit new posts to be published.  These are held in a moderation queue until an "Editor," or "Administrator" approves the post.  "Authors" can publish their own posts without waiting for review.  "Subscribers" cannot post at all but can merely read and comment on posts.

You can read more about user roles and capabilities in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).  Basically, make all of your contributing users into "Contributors" and your editors into "Editors."  Leave yourself as the "Administrator" as you'd expect.  Editors will be notified when new posts have been submitted for review.

Comment: I want the contributer not delte his/her posted item after it has been approved by the Editör.
please have a look my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979913/wordpress-user-roles-contributer-can-not-delete-his-here-post-item

Comment: That should be the default behavior.  If you look at the chart on the Codex page I referenced, it shows that Contributors are not allowed the "delete_published_posts" capability.  If you want to also disallow the "delete_posts" capability, I suggest installing a role management plug-in (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) and disabling that across the board for contributors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at a plugin called Edit Flow, which allows you to customize the options for a Post Status, so you can add more layers to your workflow than just Draft and Pending. However this plugin might not be maintained anymore.

Also, I think WP 3.0 will have some core features related to register_post_status as well (though I have hardly heard it mentioned in the community).

Comment: The register_post_status feature hasn't been fully fleshed out yet. Pushed out to v3.1