# wordpress user roles : contributer can not delete his/here post item

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Contributor can not delete/change his/her posted item after it has been published on wordpress blog.

How can I do this?

Ps: my purpose ([read this to see the big picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847658/worpress-workflow-modfications))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the way WordPress intended it = though I thought the contributor could still edit the post, but have to submit it for revision again...

Try using [WordPress Role Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/role-manager/) to add the capability `edit_published_posts` to the contributor role.